# auto generate textbox values based on a value of another textbox

Tags: vb.net

I am using the method shown below to autocomplete a textbox from database:

```
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand("SELECT CustomerID from Table", 
    Database.Connection)
    Dim AutoComp As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
    Dim dsAccount As New DataSet
    Dim sqlAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(comm)
    sqlAdapter.Fill(dsAccount)

    For i As Integer = 0 To dsAccount.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        AutoComp.Add(dsAccount.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString())
    Next

    TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = AutoComp
```

This works just fine. I have a bunch of other textboxes which I would like to be filled with the appropriate values after I have selected the value for textbox1. Basically when I select the CustomerID I would like the customerName, the contactName and the customerAddress values that are assigned to that particular CustomerID to be generated in these other textboxes.

[Screenshot of the interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF00U.png) [Auto-complete textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGD6z.png)

PS: I tried to use the same method but in a button instead of using it in the Form_Load, but it did not work.So I assumed that either it will not work that way or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: How much data do you have? If it's not too much then it would be better to retrieve it all upfront and then filter locally each time rather than going back to the database, which is a more expensive operation.

Comment: You can populate a `DataTable` with all the data and then, as required, call the `Select` method to get just the rows containing the data that matches a particular filter.

Comment: I think you can utilize in-memory collection like `DataSet` or `DataTable` to hold the data retrieved from DB, or even a list of model class to store all data and use `Where` (and `Select`) to retrieve based on certain filters.

Comment: @jmcilhinney It's a lot of data mate. Thousands of customers.

Comment: I do know how to develop the sql queries and extract the data what it seems that I am not able to do is how to auto populate the other textboxes when i select the specific CustomerID value for textbox1

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking, tbh. You only retrieve the customer id in your SQL, and there's no WHERE clause.

Comment: @peterG I retrieve the customer id with no where clause because auto complete for the textbox1 works like a drop down menu. So all the customer IDs will appear there and when the user selects an ID I wand the textboxes for the customer name, contact name and the address to be populated with the specific values assign to that particular ID in the database, using a button. The queries for that part will be separate from the query that gets the ID. I hope that makes sense i can even add a picture of the windows form design to my question to give a clear idea of what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: @peterG I have updated the question. You can now see sceenshots of the interface and auto-complete textbox(when input a letter or couple of letters it will suggest IDs starting with that string). Hope that brings sense to what I am talking about. :)

Comment: I still not sure what you're missing, tbh; typically you'd pick up the selectionchanged event, then use the selected ID as a parameter in your SQL, pull the data, populate a Client object, bind it to the form. But you say you know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are asking is how to respond to the user selecting an item from your CustomerId autocomplete list in textbox1, then you could do this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = 13 Then

        'AN AUTOCOMPLETE ITEM HAS BEEN SELECTED    

        'The customerId will be available in textbox1.text

        'Your code to get  data from the database
        'and set the values of the other textboxes

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was exactly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: There are other event handlers you can do this in where you don't need to check for KeyCode 13 and it will work even if the user changes the value and moves off the field in any other away (Tab, click on another field, etc).  I usually do it in the Validating or Validated event hander.